# Reusing extended components in other views with ExtJS4 MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4

I'm using the mvc architecture method for a ui I'm building. I have a menu that I would like to reuse and would like to know if the following is possible:

File structure:

```
app/
--->app.js
--->view/
--------->viewport.js
--------->Toolbar.js
--------->SaveMenu.js
```

viewport.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
layout: 'fit',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.Toolbar',
    'MyApp.view.SaveMenu',
],

initComponent: function () {
    this.items = {
        dockedItems: [
            {
                dock    : 'top',
                xtype   : 'myapptoolbar',
                height  : 40,
            }
        ]
...
// more config, but this works now.
```

Toolbar.js

```
Ext.define ('Myapp.view.Toolbar', {
    extend : 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias : 'widget.myapptoolbar',
    items : [
        {
            text : 'Save',
            // The following doesn't work, is there another way to achieve this?
            menu : 'myappsavemenu',  
        }
    ]
});
```

SaveMenu.js

```
Ext.define ('Myapp.view.SaveMenu', {
    extend : 'Ext.menu.Menu',
    alias : 'widget.myappsavemenu',
    items : [
        {
            text : 'Save as...',
        }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to reuse previously defined view components in other views, and if so how should I go about doing this?

Edit - Forgot the error thrown when using this configuration:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ownerCt' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly reasonable, but the menu property should be a menu instance, a menu id or an object config.

I would go with:

```
menu: {xtype: 'myappsavemenu'},
```

ExtJS docs are available online. The button's menu config is addressed here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-menu

In general, I'm just getting familiar with Ext.

Also note, the first method, which I've now removed, will give you the same menu instance across all myapptoolbars. This may or may not be a terrible thing depending on what you're doing. I try to stay away from it as it can be hard to debug when problems are introduced.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
Ext.ClassManager.parseNamespace

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see that you were setting your items statically. You might try `menu: {xtype: 'myappsavemenu'},` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much David, both methods actually work. I had a typo I didn't catch when trying the first method. Could you point me in the direction of where you learned this from, or do you have a succinct explanation?

Comment: I learned the hard way that those cryptic JavaScript errors like the one you found are often made clear if your app is using ext-dev.js or ext-all-dev.js instead of the base Ext includes.  The "dev" versions have a lot of debug code baked-in that will give you strong clues in the Firebug console when stuff goes wrong.